# How to use qualify in spark.sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

How do I write below sql query in pyspark.sql where I am not able to find alternate for qualify.

```
select * from table where id = 1 qualify transaction_ts = max(transaction_ts) over (partition by city)
```

Answer (score 1):

As there was no expected input/output provided my answer may not be accurate

Qualify does not exists in core Spark (but for example its avilable in Databricks) but i think that you can do what you want with window function used in sub-query

Here is my example in Python

```
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x = [
    (1, "Warsaw", datetime.date(2020, 10, 25)),
    (1, "Warsaw", datetime.date(2020, 10, 22)),
    (1, "Warsaw", datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)),
    (2, "Cracow", datetime.date(2020, 10, 22)),
    (2, "Cracow", datetime.date(2020, 10, 15)),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=["id", "city", "ts"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_table")
spark.sql(
    " select id, city, ts from (Select id, city, ts, MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY ts desc) AS max from test_table where id = 1) where ts = max "
).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+----------+
| id|  city|        ts|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|Warsaw|2020-10-26|
+---+------+----------+
```